# Choice of statistical test for comparing items

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures

I'm struggling with the choice of a statistical test. Here a simple example for what I wanted to do.

The question was:
After school / work / university...
a. I'd liked to go to bed. (7-point likert scale: agree - disagree)
b. I'd like to cook. (7-point likert scale: agree - disagree)
c. I'd like to watch TV. (7-point likert scale: agree - disagree)
d. I'd like to read a book. (7-point likert scale: agree - disagree)

The three options "school / work / university" in the question symbolize three groups of the questionnaire. So, every participant answered the four questions only for one of the three options and did not know about the other two.

Now, I want to calculate with there is a difference between the four activities in general but also if the activities change depending on the group (school, work, university). I thought about a two-way repeated measurements ANOVA since, I think, I have a within-factor (4 levels) and a between-factor (3 levels). However, I'm not sure if this is the best method...

I appreciate every suggestions or comment.

Thanks for your help!
Helena

Comment: I would suggest to answer the questions of interest in the context of a MANOVA model.

Comment: Seems to be a perfectly good idea - thanks! If someone has another idea, it is always welcome

Comment: Can you give sample sizes and data summaries?

Comment: I am withdrawing my Answer. It is not clear what hypothesis you want to test. If you want somehow to balance preferences for sleeping, cooking, watching TV, and reading among the three types of subjects you may be headed toward an analysis that assumes Likert-7 scores are normal. Someone else will have to help you with that.